# Set Enable date font to bold in raddatepicker

Tags: asp.net, telerik-datepicker

I am using `RadDatePicker telerik` control in my project.in picker date less than today are `disable` and others are `enable.` I want to set enable date in `bold font`. How can I do this.

Please take me out from this situation.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show the code ??

Comment: Thanks friend . This is  done now. I just use css. <style type="text/css" >
            .rcOutOfRange {
       font-weight:100 ! important;     
            }
        </style>

Comment: See the below formatted answer.

Comment: you can mark the answer as correct if it worked for you, so that it can be useful for others

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the css like below, if it is textbox:-

```
.rcOutOfRange {
        font-weight: 100 !important;
    }
```